# tabcmd commands to export csv

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to export view as csv from tableau online using below URL, but while generating csv it's only returning html.

this is the URL: `https://10az.online.tableau.com/#/site/xxx/views/xxx/AccountAdvertisersList.csv`

the same above URL is working directly with browser and giving right required data in csv form.

here is the command:

```
tabcmd get "https://10az.online.tableau.com/#/site/xxx/views/xxx/AccountAdvertisersList.csv" -f "acc.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the docs, a csv is only downloaded from views. You are passing in the entire workbook url. Try adjusting per their example.

```
tabcmd get "/views/Finance/InvestmentGrowth.csv"
```

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#id7e0a0627-ad89-4135-a1c2-85b1d8472568

Answer (score 0):

You can export to CSV via the following,

```
tabcmd export "xxx/AccountAdvertisersList" --csv -f "acc.csv"
```